# does Hibernate work with akka actor?

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, akka

my main concern is on `ThreadLocal`.
akka actors don't bind to specific thread, so any use of thread local storage will be problematic on akka actors

does Hibernate use `ThreadLocal`?

can they coexist in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. I use Hibernate (via the JPA interface) together with Akka actors.

I have two approaches to deal with multi-threading:

1. If each actor updates information that cannot conflict with other actors (for example, each row in a table will never be used by multiple actors), you can create a single entity manager per actor and use that for the life of the actor. Although, if a transaction fails it may be best to discard the entity manager.
2. Otherwise, in each invocation of the actor (via it's receive function) that needs database access, create a new entity manager, begin a transaction, access the database, commit the transaction, and then close the entity manager.

I have the first approach running in production systems.