# Hibernate using akka actors

Tags: spring, hibernate, scala, jdbc, akka

I would like to read and process a whole table of accounts using akka actors. We have a multi-threaded actors framework that currently does this using simple jdbc queries that read "chunks" of the data. We now want to take advantage of JPA/Hibernate's mapping and object graph. We have a spring application.

How do I use Hibernate and still take advantage of the multi-threading? My experience with Hibernate is creating DAOs with an EntityManager and calling myDao.getById(...) but how do I work on data that we have ALREADY fetched using jdbc and now manage it using Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use hibernate with akka actors you just should be carefully and follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094781/does-hibernate-work-with-akka-actor).

But for using actors with an ORM I recommend you [SORM](http://sorm-framework.org/)

> SORM is a Scala ORM-framework designed to eliminate boilerplate code
> and solve the problems of scalability with a high level abstraction
> and a functional programming style. Features
>
> Complete abstraction from relational concepts. You work with case classes, collections and other standard Scala data types instead of
> tables, rows, foreign keys and relations.
>
> Complete separation of domain model from persistence layer. There are no annotations, special types or any other dependencies on persistence layer present in model declaration. This house is clear!
>
> An intuitive and centralized connection-agnostic API. No tangled implicit constructions polluting your namespace and functionality scattered across multiple components. No manual management of connections.
>
> **Concurrency. A single SORM instance can safely be used across multiple threads and seamlessly integrates into actor-based concurrent systems, like Akka**.
>
> Integrated connection pooling. Scalable just by setting a “poolSize” parameter.
>
> Automated schema generation.